# Deploying multi-region AppSync API with latency-based routing custom-domain via CDK

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk, amazon-route53, aws-appsync

I am attempting to deploy an AWS AppSync API into two AWS regions (accessible via the same hostname - using Route53 latency-based routing) using CDK.

I first ran into the issue that I couldn't deploy an AWS::AppSync::DomainName resource into the second region using the same custom-domain name as the first region, I was experiencing CloudFormation failures which stated:

> Invalid request provided: CNAME already exists

This was my assumption about how this ought to be configured:

```
                   |-----------------------------|
                   | my-appsync-api.example.com  |
                   | 2 CNAMES: 1 x ase2, 1 x ew1 |
                   |-----------------------------|
                                  |
               ------------------------------------------
               |                                        |
    |----------------------------|        |----------------------------|
    | my-appsync-api.example.com |        | my-appsync-api.example.com |
    | AppSync custom domain name |        | AppSync custom domain name |
    |----------------------------|        |----------------------------|
               |                                        |
     |---------------------|                 |--------------------|
     | ase2.cloudfront.net |                 | ew1.cloudfront.net |
     |---------------------|                 |--------------------|
               |                                        |
          |---------|                              |---------|
          | AppSync |                              | AppSync |
          |---------|                              |---------|
```

Given I had setup my Route53 records as CNAMES, I assumed that I should change those to be A records using AWS' alias feature to point at the AppSync domain name. However, although this is possible via the Route53 console, it is not possible via the CDK. When I tried to set this up, I found that there is currently no Route53 target for AppSync (as there is for ApiGateway, CloudFront etc...).

My next attempt was to configure region-specific custom-domain names for each AWS::AppSync::DomainName resources, and create region-specific CNAMES for each; then finally create latency-based routing A records with the desired domain name which route to their respective region-specific domain:

```
                   |-----------------------------|
                   | my-appsync-api.example.com  |
                   | 2 CNAMES: 1 x ase2, 1 x ew1 |
                   |-----------------------------|
                                  |
               -------------------------------------------
               |                                         |
|---------------------------------|      |--------------------------------|
| my-ase2-appsync-api.example.com |      | my-ew1-appsync-api.example.com |
| CNAME for ase2                  |      | CNAME for ew1                  |
|---------------------------------|      |--------------------------------|
               |                                         |
|---------------------------------|      |--------------------------------|
| my-ase2-appsync-api.example.com |      | my-ew1-appsync-api.example.com |
| AppSync custom domain name      |      | AppSync custom domain name     |
|---------------------------------|      |--------------------------------|
               |                                         |
     |---------------------|                  |--------------------|
     | ase2.cloudfront.net |                  | ew1.cloudfront.net |
     |---------------------|                  |--------------------|
               |                                         |
          |---------|                               |---------|
          | AppSync |                               | AppSync |
          |---------|                               |---------|
```

Alas, this did not work either, I ended up with an SSL issue, I assume because the CloudFront distribution (under the hood of AppSync) was configured with the region-specific domain.

It looks to me like the **only** option I have (given it appears that you can only have AWS::AppSync::DomainName resources with unique custom domain names) is to have a unique custom domain name per-region and then pop an API Gateway proxy in-front of AppSync... although, it adds around 200ms (at least) of latency this way. It'd be great if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/reduce-latency-for-end-users-with-multi-region-apis-with-cloudfront/) blog post by AWS?
The setup looks like something you try to achieve.